# WPF textblock which allows the selection of text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `TextBlock` in my app that has text with some URLs in it. At the same time, I want the text to be selectable and copyable. If I use the `TextBox` element I loose the ability to add `Hyperlink`s and if I use the `TextBlock` I loose the selection functionality.

Having all that said, what do you suggest to keep both the hyperlinks and the select (with mouse and keyboard) ability?

Edit: this application is a chat app, and I want the incoming message to be selectable while the URL are clickable.

Comment: I think [`RichTextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you're looking for

Comment: @dkozl thanks for your reply, I don't know how to add the hyperlinks to a RichTextBox, currently in a TextBlock I am adding using TextBlock.Inlines.Add to add hyperlinks. I mean I did google it but RichTextBox is a lot different, maybe I should start learning that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure but perhaps you can use RichTextBox. See: [Adding hyperlink in textbox](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7202b152-2c4f-4b06-8ebf-474f193d7db9/adding-hyperlink-in-textbox?forum=wpf).

You will have to manage to find links when the user type one and modify the text in accordance (inserting an hyperlink) with the user text. Or add a way, like a ContextualMenu, to offer the user to add an hyperlink.

I'm not sure you can find a control that do exactly what you want. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The Webbrowser control will allow text selection and hyperlinks.

Comment: The webbrowser is not a text editing control, it is a web browser. I want a text element.

Comment: A textblock is not for text editing either. It purely displays text. If you need to edit text then you need a text box.

Comment: I actually need to select, not edit. I need both click on hyperlinks and text selection.

Comment: You can do this with a web browser control using the navigatetostring() method and passing HTML to it which can consist of text and/or hyperlinks. It's actually a fairly common workaround in wpf and silverlight for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<Label>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="bob@contoso.com">
        <Run Text="bob@contoso.com"/>
    </Hyperlink>
</Label>
```

You can style appropriately and add commands to Hyperlink if you want to actually navigate to that link when clicked